# Cannot call setState() when attempting to update list in todo app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

This seems to be a common issue, but I've tried several configurations and am consistently getting the error message `Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted`. I have used `setState()` in similar ways in other components of my app without issue, so I'm not sure why my `App` component thinks I'm trying to call `setState()` in the constructor when it is very clearly outside of it.

This is my attempt to use the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method. There is clearly something I am fully missing about this, but I can't glean much reading the documentation for `setState()`. *Especially* considering that I am using this exact, same syntax in other parts of my app without issue. At any rate, here's what I'm working with:

```
import react from 'react';

class App extends react.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tasks: [
        {
          content:"walk dog",
          date:"7/17/21",
          priority:"high"
        },
        {
          content:"take out trash",
          date:"7/17/21",
          priority:"low"
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
  }
  addTask(content, date, priority) {
    let taskUpdate = this.state.tasks;
    let task = {
      content: content,
      date: date,
      priority: priority
    };
    taskUpdate.push(task);
    this.setState({
      tasks: taskUpdate
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Sidebar taskList={this.state.tasks} groupList={this.state.groups}>
        </Sidebar>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export { App };
```

The gist of this is to update the state of my `App` component so that I can pass as props and re-render the list of tasks within the `Sidebar` component. Apologies in advance since this seems to have been asked a million times, but I am simply confounded.

***EDIT***

For clarification, the `addTask` method is called within a form that is rendered as part of an "add this task to the list of tasks" modal, e.g.:

```
const AddModal = ({ closeBtn, show, children }) => {
    class Form extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                content: '',
                date: '',
                highPriority: ''
            };
            this.handleContent = this.handleContent.bind(this);
            this.handleDate = this.handleDate.bind(this);
            this.handlePriority = this.handlePriority.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }
        handleContent(event) {
            this.setState({content: event.target.value});
        }
        handleDate(event) {
            this.setState({date: event.target.value});
        }
        handlePriority(event) {
            this.setState({highPriority: event.target.checked});
        }
        handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("content: " + this.state.content + "\n" + 
                        "date: " + this.state.date + "\n" +
                        "high priority: " + this.state.highPriority);
            new App().addTask(this.state.content, this.state.date, this.state.highPriority);
            closeBtn();
            
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input 
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.content} 
                    onChange={this.handleContent}
                    placeholder="add a task (max 30 chars)"
                    maxLength="30"></input>
    
                    <input 
                    type="date"
                    onChange={this.handleDate}></input>
    
                    <div className="checkbox-container">
                        <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="priority-checkbox"
                        onChange={this.handlePriority}></input>
                        <label
                        htmlFor="priority-checkbox">
                            high priority?
                        </label>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            id="add-task-submit">
                            +
                        </button>
                    </div>
    
                    
                </form>
            );
        }
    };

    const modalClassName = show ? "add-task-modal display-block" : "add-task-modal display-none";
    return ( 
        <div className={modalClassName}>
            <div className="add-task-modal-content">
                {children}
                <button type="button" id="close-btn" onClick={closeBtn}>
                    x
                </button>

                <Form></Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The modal containing this form is rendered in a file that simply displays a list of tasks. The `addTask()` method is successful in passing form data to 'App.js' as I can change the state directly, e.g. `this.state.tasks = [...]`, but from what I have read this is extremely not best practice, and I need to use `setState()` instead.

**EDIT 2**

So what started as me stumbling over a simple issue of altering state turned into a succinct and useful overview of react as a framework. Big thanks to user Robin Zigmond for the write-up and to  Alexander Staroselsky for expounding even further with the suggestion of using the redux library. Your input helped immensely, and the components of my app are now correctly communicating with one another.

Suffice it to say my initial bug was not really an issue with `setState`, this has been instrumental in helping me understand react on a broader level. Thanks again to everyone who contributed.

Comment: Where is addTask being called exactly?

Comment: Is this the full component? I don't see anywhere `addTask` is called, and that's the only method that calls `setState`. I do note that `this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);` should be in the constructor, not `componentDidMount`, and that might well cause you issues - but it shouldn't cause this particular console warning as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky `addTask()` is called when submitting a form in a modal window. This function works fine if I update the state directly, e.g. `this.state.tasks = ...`, but I want to use `setState()` so that I can actually render the change to the list. Or at least that's my understanding of `setState()`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have also attempted to bind the function in the constructor, but I get the same error. `addTask` is called in an "add this task to the list of tasks" modal elsewhere in the app. As mentioned in another comment, the function works perfectly well when I update the state directly, e.g. `this.state.tasks = ...`, but I realize that is not best practice, and I would like to actually utilize the `setState()` method.

Comment: Have you changed something in your webpack config?? Maybe this issue is caused by some configuration. Or some third party package maybe causing it.

Comment: @hbarnett91 so it sounds like you are indeed calling this somewhere you don't show us in the original question. Could you add that? The warning you are getting indicates that you are calling it before this component has mounted, it's hard to suggest how to fix it before seeing how you are actually calling it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have updated my OP to include the modal in which `addTask` is called. Perhaps I am thinking about this totally wrong. Is `App` not mounted by the time everything is rendered to the extent that I could even access the button that calls `addTask`? Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed show exactly what you are doing wrong - which seems to be based on a large misunderstanding about how React works. I will type up my thoughts into an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be seen here in your `AddModal` component:

```
new App().addTask(this.state.content, this.state.date, this.state.highPriority);
```

Manually making a new instance of one of your components - as you do here with `new App()` - is not something that you should ever need to do in React. The framework itself handles the lifecycle of all components - including constructing them.

The warning itself is revealing in this context: "Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted". "mounted" is a concept in React which refers simply to whether a component instance is yet rendered as part of your user interface - in other words, whether it is on the page or not. React is a library/framework whose sole purpose is to build a user interface - and each component should be something where you could point a non-technical user to part of your page/app and say "that is the part this component controls". It doesn't make any sense to have a component instance that isn't actually rendered (or "mounted" to use the React term) on the page.

Technically, React will not even call the constructor of your class until it is ready to "mount" the component - so after the constructor is called, React will call your component's `render` method and then (if it has one) its `componentDidMount` method. (See React component lifecycle diagram [here](https://i0.wp.com/programmingwithmosh.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Screen-Shot-2018-10-31-at-1.44.28-PM.png?ssl=1).) React handles all this itself when you include a component in your JSX inside `render` - so you don't have to worry about it. But by manually instantiating `new App()` you are precisely constructing a component instance without mounting it, which React is not designed to deal with, and therefore it justifiably complains.

What you appear to be trying to do doesn't make sense on a deeper level - because you are trying to update component state, but the component shouldn't *have* any state when it's not yet mounted. Again, state should be something that corresponds to something in your UI, even on a slightly abstract level - it might be what the user has currently typed into an input field, or something a bit more abstract like a flag to say that some action has or hasn't been done, or a count of the number of times a particular action has been done - or whatever else you feel like. But it corresponds to *something*, and that something is intimately linked to what is going on inside your component on the page. If it's not on the page - then what is your state actually for?

To return to what you should actually do: I assume your `App` is the root component of your application, and that `AddModal` appears somewhere inside it. If it were a direct child, this would be simple, because your `App` is always rendered when `AddModal` is and you can simply pass the `addTask` method down as a prop. In other words, somewhere inside `render` in `App`, you would have:

```
<AddModal addTask={ this.addTask } />
```

and then inside `AddModal` call this as:

```
this.props.addTask(/*whatever arguments you need*/);
```

which would update the state of the parent component to what you need. (Which here seems to be updating the data inside the `Sidebar` component.)

If, as seems likely, the `AddModal` is actually several levels down, you have to pass `addTask` down several levels. Ie. inside `render` of `App` you would have

```
<SomeChildComponent addTask={ this.addTask } />
```

then inside `SomeChildComponent`, say

```
<SomeOtherChild addTask={ this.props.addTask } />
```

and so on down whatever levels you need, until you finally reach

```
<AddModal addTask={ this.props.addTask } />
```

If you have more than 1 or 2 levels of this and don't need the `addTask` on the intermediate levels, this certainly gets tedious and brittle - so you may want to look at other solutions like context, or Redux. But this is how you do things in "basic React", and I think you'd do well to understand this before looking too hard at other patterns. (I'm a big believer in needing to understand what problems libraries like Redux are solving before just diving into using them because "everyone else does".)

I'd also recommend reading [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for an understanding of how to deal with situations where one component needs to update the state of another which isn't a direct child or parent - which seems to be what you're trying to do.

Apologies if I've been rambling, but I hope this gives you a better handle on how React works and how to deal with state, and why you shouldn't be manually constructing your own components.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the explanation. This makes react make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mutate array in place, when you use `push` reference to array doesn't change. But not sure if this related to your warning.

```
  addTask(content, date, priority) {
    this.setState({
      tasks: this.state.tasks.concat({
        content,
        date,
        priority
      })
    });
  }
```

Why you calling `addTask` with `new`? You not supposed to do this.

```
new App().addTask(this.state.content, this.state.date, this.state.highPriority);
```

Can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or `redux` for pass value and update function to modal.

Comment: This is much cleaner, thank you. Unfortunately I am still receiving the same error, so the search continues.

Comment: Need more info, how you pass addTask cb and how you use it, because don't see anything wrong except mutating array.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the modal in which `addTask` is called.

Comment: Possible that you call `addTask` with `new`, shouldn't do like this.

Comment: `new App().addTask()` is my ad hoc solution to pass form data to be handled by the main logic of my application. It didn't seem right when I was typing it out, but it does successfully return data from my form/modal.

Comment: Try to comment it out and see if warning disappear, sure it's not right.

Comment: This does remove the error since the method is no longer being called. What led to my initial 'solution' was attempting to export a function that updates the state of `App` from another part of the application. I'm not sure how to get `addTask` to work the way I need it to.

Comment: You can use `context` to pass `addTask` from top parent component to modal.

Comment: I suspect this will work perfectly once I am able to get back to my computer. I think part of my problem from the start was thinking too much in terms of imports and exports instead of using the sort of cascading effect from parent to child components with regard to their methods. I'll update as soon as I can, thank you so much for your help this far.

Comment: Both yours and user Robin Zigmond's advice helped me fix my problem, which was obviously a misunderstanding on my part in handling props from parent to child in react. Thank you so much for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your addTask function with this:

```
addTask(content, date, priority) {
    
    let task = {
      content: content,
      date: date,
      priority: priority
    };
    
    this.setState({
      tasks: [...this.state.tasks, task]
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is another method I attempted, but the error persists. Thank you for the recommendation.